# How to fetch data from two tables in one while loop?

Tags: php

Is there any way to fetch data from two tables using only one while loop?

Here is code:

```
<?php

$sql=mysql_query("select *from pm where send_to='$_GET[name]' limit $offset, $rowsperpage");

$sql2=mysql_query("select *from pm_reply where send_to='$_GET[name]' limit $offset, $rowsperpage");

$start_from = $offset + 1; 
echo "<ol start='$start_from'>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

{

echo"<li>From: <a href='profile.php?name=$rows[send_by]'>$rows[send_by]</a><br><br><a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:14pt;' href='view_pm.php?name=$_GET[name]&pm=$rows[subject]'>$rows[subject]</a></li>"; 

echo "<hr>";
echo "<br>";
}

while($rows2=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2))
{
echo"<li>From: <a href='profile.php?name=$rows2[replied_by]'>$rows2[replied_by]</a><br><br><a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:14pt;' href='view_pm.php?name=$_GET[name]&pm=$rows2[subject]'>$rows2[subject]</a></li>"; 

echo "<hr>";
echo "<br>"
}

echo "</ol>";
?>
```

Comment: sure you can, one might finish earlier than the other so you'd have to check that too

Comment: combine both query, by join or union ... it depends upon your db structure ..

Comment: Yes, try use `JOIN` but both tables need to has same field like `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Your working style is not correct
**Join** both tables using **keys**
Then make join query 
**Make life easy :)**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a resultset variable using a inner join or a multiple select
`Select A.date1, B.date2 from table1 A, table2 B where ...`
then you can treat as a single resultset
Or you can use the sentence 'between' if you are searching for data between the dates
`Select sales from table where dates between 'date1' and 'date2'`

Comment: can you plz give me full example?

Comment: Select A.*, B.* from pm A, pm_reply B where A.send_to='$_GET[name]' and B.send_to='$_GET[name]'
This will extract all the fields in each table, make sure to extract only the fields what you need

Answer (score 0):

nothing prevents you to write

```
while(($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) OR ($rows2=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)))
{
    if ($rows)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if ($rows2)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but this code "smells"